# Jira Startup failed with unloaded plugins

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I was deploying a Jira report plugin with SDK 3.10 and ran into this:

The following plugins are required by JIRA, but have not been started:

```
Gadget Directory Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.directory)
Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - Project Config Plugin (com.atlassian.jira.jira-project-    config-plugin)
Atlassian OAuth Admin Plugin (com.atlassian.oauth.admin)
Embedded Gadgets Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.embedded)
Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - Shared Application Access Layer (SAL) Plugin(com.atlassian.sal.jira)
Gadget Dashboard Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard)
Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - Look And Feel Logo Upload Plugin (com.atlassian.jira.lookandfeel)
Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - Gadgets Plugin (com.atlassian.jira.gadgets)
Atlassian REST - Module Types (com.atlassian.plugins.rest.atlassian-rest-module)
FishEye Plugin (com.atlassian.jirafisheyeplugin)
Gadget Spec Publisher Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher)
Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - REST Plugin (com.atlassian.jira.rest)
Atlassian OAuth Service Provider Plugin (com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider)
Opensocial Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.opensocial)
```

RemarK: i do not have Jira installed on my laptop. is that a problem? also, I am using Java SE 1.6

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to provide more information, for example pom.xml base pom and dependencies, and maybe some logs. JIRA SDK produces compilation log file, that you could include.
Another thing, you could skip harness test. Try to build plugin with:

mvn clean package -Patlassian -Dmaven.test.skip=true